# Has any Marvel or DC character been played by the same person, first in cartoon and then in live-action?

Tags: marvel, dc, actors

I know that voice actors tend not to do much camera acting.  (The same can't be said in reverse, of course; camera actors lend their voices to movies and TV shows all the time.)  But are there any Marvel or DC characters who appeared in an animated movie or TV show and *then* were played by the same person in a live-action movie or TV show?

The reason I specify "animated-then-live" is to hopefully focus on people who are primarily voice actors, and also to rule out any animated works that are intended to be direct spin-offs of the MCU/DCEU.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[Megalyn Echikunwoke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megalyn_Echikunwoke) played Vixen first in an [animated webseries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vixen_(web_series)) (premiered 25 August 2015), then later in the live-action *Arrow* series in [an episode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Arrow_episodes#ep84) that aired on 24 February 2016.

[image: Vixen (animated)]

[image: Vixen (live)]

Comment: Perhaps you could add pictures of the animated Vixen and the live action Vixen.

Answer (score 23):

Mark Hamill first played [*The Trickster*](http://theflash.wikia.com/wiki/The_Trickster_%28Mark_Hamill%29) in the 1990 live action TV series *The Flash*, then voiced the part in the 2004 animated series *Justice League Unlimited* and then went on to appear in the 2014 live action *The Flash*.

Comment: And if people are wondering if he counts as primarily a voice actor: yes if you look at this century. His [IMDB page](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000434/?ref_=nv_sr_1) mentions a huge number of voice performances, but no live action roles whatsoever between 2004 and 2010.

Answer (score 6):

[Michael Rosenbaum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Rosenbaum), who played Lex Luthor on the live-action TV series
[*Smallville*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smallville), provided the voice for The Flash (Wally West) on the animated series [*Justice League Unlimited*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justice_League_Unlimited).  In the *JLU* episode ["The Great Brain Robbery"](http://dcau.wikia.com/wiki/The_Great_Brain_Robbery), when Luthor and Flash swapped bodies, Rosenbaum reprised his role as Luthor in animated form:

*Smallville* ran from October 16, 2001 to May 13, 2011, and Rosenbaum appeared in episodes ranging from the pilot to the finale.  "The Great Brain Robbery" first aired on March 4, 2006, midway through Rosenbaum's time on *Smallville*.

Comment: The question specifically mentions animated ***first***, which seems to disqualify having been in the live action *both before and after*.

Comment: @Gnemlock - The question in the subject line did not include that requirement at the time I answered.  When I later saw the requirement in the body of the post, I edited the subject line to include it (rather than the other way around), to respect the OP's intent.  I think honest answerers deserve some respect, though, too.  After putting work into answering, in good faith, a question that an OP asks, it's fair to keep the answer "grandfathered" when the question is revised.

Comment: The question in the body has been the same since it was posted. The only edit to the question, thus far, is an edit you made, yourself.

Comment: @Gnemlock - The original post asked *two* questions.  I answered the one I read -- which, as the first and most prominently displayed of the two, could be considered the primary question -- and then I saw the other. I think that I handled it in a respectful way, rather than voting to close the original post until the OP could edit it down to a single question.

Answer (score 5):

Russell Tovey Played The Ray in the animated Freedom Fighters series, and played him on the Earth-X crossover.  The two were produced at the same time, and the series might have premiered after the TV show, but they may be close enough to satisfy the spirit of the question.

Even though it's the inverse of the question, I can only think of one other person (aside the two mentioned here) who's played the same character in a live-action Marvel film and in animation.  Lou Ferrigno has provided the voice of the the Hulk in a number of media, including animated and the Marvel films up until Thor:Raganrok, when Mark Ruffalo took over the voice role.

On the DC Side, Adam West and Burt Ward returned to voice the Dynamic Duo for Filmation's New Adventures of Batman, and West (IIRC) voiced Batman for at least one Super Friends series. Bud Collyer voiced Superman for the original radio series, and returned to voice him for the Filmation cartoons.

Comment: I seem to recall a couple of Spider-Man actors returned to voice him for video games, but don't have the details at hand, so I mention it here and not as part of the answer. Anyone?

Comment: A couple more live action first examples: Adam West voiced Batman on later seasons of Super Friends; Billy Dee Williams played Harvey Dent in Batman and Two-Face in the LEGO Batman Movie.

Comment: Also on the reverse-of-the-question side, Clark Gregg's generally been up for voicing Agent Coulson in cartoons and video games though that's a bit of a weird case since he wasn't created for the comics initially.

Comment: Ah yes, he played "Principal Coulson" on the last Spider-Man series, and in the Lego video game(s)

Answer (score 2):

This is a borderline case, but Paul Bettany voiced AI Jarvis in MCU movies before appearing "in flesh" as Vision.

Answer (score 1):

In the Arrow episode [Suicide Squad](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3337660/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_123), they show a brief glimpse of a character credited as "Deranged Squad Female" who was meant to be Harley Quinn as an Easter egg. She was played by Cassidy Alexa but her voice was played by [Tara Strong](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0152839/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t25), who has voiced her in many DC animated movies and video games.